# Can matplotlib generate EPS10 output?

Tags: matplotlib, transparency, eps

EPS10 supports transparency and layers in vector graphics. Can matplotlib generate EPS10 files?

Comment: I am not familiar with what EPS10 exactly is. However, does the *Agg* backend not allow you to output files in EPS format.

Comment: EPS yes, but not EPS10.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the EPS10 spec?  This sounds very interesting, but I have never heard of this file format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am fairly sure that `matplotlib` cannot do this.  Indeed, I do not think that `EPS10` is a specified version of EPS, but rather than it is just a tag to denote `.eps` files saved by Adobe illustrator version 10 (or above) with the "Illustator 10 EPS" option.  [This forum thread](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1126797) seems to support that view.

I can't find a canonical reference on the Adobe site as I'd like, but [this blog / article](http://design.tutsplus.com/articles/help-with-selling-vector-stock-in-eps10-format--vector-6023) does a good job of explaining what it does and the fact that it is an option on saving EPS in later Illustrator versions.

As a side note - it looks like the format is obsolete in the most modern versions of Illustrator ([see forum question here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1443708))